# Hiding breadcrumbs on cart page in woocommerce with storefront theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to hide breadcrumbs with a child theme of storefront. This is the code I have in functions.php however, the conditional does not fire when on the cart page. Removing the conditional causes the breadcrumbs to be hidden

```
add_action('init', 'remove_shop_breadcrumbs' );
function remove_shop_breadcrumbs()
{
    if ( is_cart()) 
    {
        remove_action( 'storefront_content_top', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb',  10 );
    }
}
```

From everything I can read, this is correct, does storefront replace this conditional with its own code, hence causing this to fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're code is firing too early. The init hook is triggered before the queries have been run therefore `is_cart()` won't work. Use the `wp` action instead.

Change this:

```
add_action('init', 'remove_shop_breadcrumbs' );
```

To this:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'remove_shop_breadcrumbs' );
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. This is interesting, because I actually got the init hook from the docs of woothemes!